# How can I enter value in excle cell contain many words and search for in database

Tags: excel, vba

How can I enter value in excel cell contain many words and search for in database if any word in the search cell matched the words in database just appear for me

am trying to write code but the problem that the code search for one word only and if I write may words in cell the code doesn't work

```
Sub searchkey()

Dim i As Integer
Dim keyword As String
Dim findrow As Integer

Sheet1.Range("b5:b20").ClearContents

keyword = Sheets("Search").Range("B2").Value
findrow = Sheets("Database").Range("B30").End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("Database").Activate
For i = 2 To findrow
    If Sheet2.Cells(i, 2) = keyword Then
        Sheet2.Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 2)).Copy
        Sheets("Search").Range("B20").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
        
        End If
Next i

Sheet1.Activate


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the `keyword` into pieces (in below code, I've called them `keywordpart`) and search for each one:

```
Sub searchkey()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim keyword As String, keywordpart As Variant
    Dim findrow As Integer
    
    Dim wsSearch As Worksheet
    Dim wsDatabase As Worksheet
    
    Set wsSearch = Sheets("Search")
    Set wsDatabase = Sheets("Database")
    
    wsSearch.Range("b5:b20").ClearContents
    
    keyword = wsSearch.Range("B2").Value
    findrow = wsDatabase.Range("B30").End(xlUp).Row
    
    For Each keywordpart In Split(keyword, " ")
        For i = 2 To findrow
            If wsDatabase.Cells(i, 2) = keywordpart Then
                wsDatabase.Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 2)).Copy
                wsSearch.Range("B20").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
            End If
        Next i
    Next

End Sub
```

I also took the liberty of tidying up your worksheet referencing - as you sometimes referenced them by name and other times by object name.

Comment: ", Sorbitol. Hydrated Silica.Disodium Pyrophosphate. Sodium Lauryl Sulfate, Flavor, Cellulose Gum, Sodium Hydroxide, Sodium Saccharin, Carbomber, Mica, Titanium Dioxide, Color" i tryied to enter this keyword in the search bar but it doesn't work

Comment: `Split(keyword, " ")` splits the keyword by spaces. If you want to split it by comma-space (as per your example), then change it to `Split(keyword, ", ")`. Also, make sure you don't include full stops/periods.